# Prove or disprove that for every $n\in \mathbb N$ there exist $k,l\in \mathbb N_0$ such that $n=5k+7l$

Tags: analysis

> Prove or disprove that for every $n\in \mathbb N$ and $n \ge 12$ there exist $k,l\in \mathbb N_0$ such that $n=5k+7l$

I was thinking that by giving a counterexample for ex 13. we could directly say that is it is not correct. I has been an exam question that it is why i am asking. Or should I try showing by induction and that conclude in a contradiction.

Comment: I edited your question, because the original version lacked  qualifier: _there exist_ $k,l$ such that the property holds. Also, please tag more carefully: this is not analysis.

Comment: Yes one counterexample suffices. The simplest example would be $n=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Since the statement is not true a single counterexample suffices. The simplest counterexample is $n=1$, as $5k+7l \geq 5$ since they are both non-negative and one at least 1...

As you observed $n=13$ is also a counterexample, which can be proven easily by observing that there are only very few many pairs $(k,l)$ so that $5k \leq 13 $ and $7l \leq 13$ and check  all of them.

The statement is actually true for all $n \geq 36$, and it can be proven by induction. You find examples for $n=36,37,38,39,40$ and then you prove that $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+5)$. If $k,l$ can be zero the statement is true for $n \geq 31$.

Note that $n \geq 36$ actually comes from $n > 5 \cdot 7$, I wonder if your instructor calculated $5+7$ instead ;)

Comment: Wow! Nice observation. +1